# Getting gibberish in the PDF when compiling latex

Tags: errors

I am seeing some gibberish paragraph that shows up on the PDF but it is not anywhere in the tex document:

> In the next lab we will be free to use address 00 for any design
>   needs. Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin vel,
>   wisi. Morbi auctor lorem non justo. Nam lacus libero, pretium at,
>   lobortis vitae, ultricies et, tellus. Donec aliquet, tortor sed
>   accumsan bibendum, erat ligula aliquet magna, vitae ornare odiometus a
>   mi. Morbi ac orci et nisl hendrerit mollis. Suspendisse ut massa. Cras
>   necante. Pellentesque a nulla. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis
>   dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aliquam tincidunt urna.
>   Nulla ullamcorper vestibu-lum turpis. Pellentesque cursus luctus
>   mauris.

Here is the code in that area. There is nothing there other than some text and a table. I searched the whole document and did not find any of these words anywhere.
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
\section{Assembling the Register File and the ALU}

The second part of this lab assignment is to create the \textit{register file}
using a 2D array of \textit{registers} and connect it to the ALU. 
The goal of this is to show the data flowing between ALU and a memory element. In the next lab we will elaborate this design into a \texttt{MIPS Based - Single cycle Processor}.

We will implement the register file using the array feature of the verilog language
which allows us to define a 2D array. Based on our design specification, 
this array should contain four 9-bit registers.
\begin{figure}[!htb]
  \centering
  \epsfig{file=pictures/lab3_regfile.eps,width=6in}
  \caption{Register File specification(a) Register File dimensions(b)}
  \label{fig:reg_file-spec}
\end{figure}

Figure~\ref{fig:reg_file-spec}(a) shows the register file interface. \\
\textit{wr\_data[8:0]} signal is data input; The data word is written into the
register file on positive edge of the clock. The destination register number (address of row) in the register file
 is determined by \textit{wr\_ad[1:0]} input. For the Read cycle,, the 
\textit{rd0\_data[8:0]} and \textit{rd1\_data[8:0]} are data outputs.
```

Comment: Search for `\lipsum`

Comment: unrelated but unless you are particularly needing to emulate documents from the 1980's do not use `\epsfig`.  LaTeX has had a standard graphics inclusion mechanism since 1993.

Comment: I do have \lipsum.....

Comment: The documentation of the `lipsum` package and the web page to which it refers (http://lipsum.com/) will explain why you got gibberish and why anyone would want gibberish.  There are other packages with a similar purpose (e.g., `kantlipsum`).

Comment: And David, I looked up the latest graphics, that was a great comment, thanks!!